# Can't change the size of UISearchbar's text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` created in `InterfaceBuilder` and `IBOutlet` of it called `userSearchBar`. Now I  want to change its width and height in code and can't do it. Here is my code:

```
    for (UIView * const subview in userSearchBar.subviews) {

    if ([subview isKindOfClass: NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if ([subview isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {

        UITextField * const textField = (UITextField *)subview;

        textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        textField.text = @"Enter text";
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);
    }
}
```

All other changes (text, color, removing bar) works perfectly but changing the size not.

Comment: Did you try something like `[searchBar sizeToFit]` or `[searchBar setNeedsDisplay]` after changing the frame of the `UITextField` (assuming that `searchBar` is your `UISearchBar`)? Try that, if that doesn't help, we will figure out something else ;) Good Luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've come up against exactly this myself, and I found the best way through was to write my own search bar from scratch, subclassing `UIView`. This gives me legitimate access to all the properties I might want to customise (such as background, colour when considering design or brand), rather than trying hack through like this. It's future proof, not that hard, and not hugely time consuming. It's a fun exercise and will deliver exactly what you want.